# Count number of fields in a document mongo Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a collection containing following documents -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e7a51b4a66e30330151847"),
    "host" : "myTestHost.com",
    "sessionId" : "daxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx1",
    "ssoId" : "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
    "days" : {
            "13" : NumberLong(130),
            "11" : NumberLong(457),
            "10" : NumberLong(77)
    },
    "count" : NumberLong(664),
    "timeStamp" : NumberLong("1458021713370")
}
```

I am using mongo java driver 3.2.1.
This document contains an embedded document 'days', that holds a specific count for each day of month.
I need to find the number of days for which a count is present.For example - for above document mentioned, the number of days for which count is present is 3 (13th, 11th and 10th day of month).
I know how to get the count on mongo console -

```
mongos>var count = 0;
mongos> db.monthData.find({},{days:1}).forEach(function(record){for(f in record.days) { count++;}});
mongos> count;
```

I need to convert this to java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can reshape your schema as follow:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e7a51b4a66e30330151847"), 
    "host" : "myTestHost.com", 
    "sessionId" : "daxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx1", 
    "ssoId" : "xxxxxx@gmail.com", 
    "days" : [
        {
            "13" : NumberLong(130)
        }, 
        {
            "11" : NumberLong(457)
        }, 
        {
            "10" : NumberLong(77)
        }
    ], 
    "count" : NumberLong(664), 
    "timeStamp" : NumberLong(1458021713370)
}
```

`days` becomes an array of objects and in this way you can easily use aggregation pipeline to know how many elements are in `days` array:

```
>db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {$match:{days:{"$exists":1}}},
        {$project:{
          numberOfDays: {$size:"$days"},
          _id:1}
        }
    ]
)
```

The aggregation returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e7a51b4a66e30330151847"), "numberOfDays" : 3 }
```

To use Aggregation Pipeline with Java driver see [`aggregate`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html?&_ga=1.212862292.1368314530.1457813240#aggregate-java.util.List-), [`AggregateIterable`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/AggregateIterable.html?_ga=1.212862292.1368314530.1457813240), [`Block`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/Block.html?_ga=1.212862292.1368314530.1457813240) and read [`Data Aggregation with Java Driver`](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/aggregation/)

Comment: $exists will not use indexes so if we have records in millions it will be slower i think. Please suggests.